# How to create sub-domain or sub-directory in localhost for new site using wpmu?

Tags: wordpress

I have one query regarding wpmu, 
 I tried to create new site using sub-domain in my localhost using wpmu but I am not able
 to do it.
 I have used this link to setup wpmu in my localhost.
 [Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

When I tried with sub-domain then it give this error
[image]

Then I tried it with sub-directory, then it created the new site for me but the theme is not visible at all

> [image]

Comment: Refer my answer on the previous question
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/15289534/1010290][1]

Hope it helps
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15289534/1010290