# Wordpress Multisite wp-config-php configuration

Tags: wordpress

Question good people..first I want to say that I tirelessly researched this before I came here as I usually do bolster my learning experience but now I need help. There were some posts and websites close to my problem but didn't exactly address my issue. I will appreciate your assistance.

I have a wordpress site in it's own directory (mysite.com/public). I recently converted it into a multisite network. The installation went well. My problem is that when I navigate to "My Sites -> Network Admin -> Dashboard" it goes to http://mysite.com/wp-admin/network/ which gives me an error404. My home dashboard includeds the public directory: http://mysite.com/public/wp-admin/ but the network dashboard does not. BUT if I type in the word public in the link address (http://mysite.com/public/wp-admin/network/) all is well.

In my wp-config-php I have it configured as this:

```
 define('WP_DEBUG', false);
 define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
 define('MULTISITE', true);
 define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
 define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.com');
 define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
 define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
 define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
 /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

So I tried to manually type in "public" on the path line:

```
 define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/public/');
```

but then I get this browser error message:
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://mysite.com/public/wp-admin/network/

So I am stuck at this point. I will appreciate anyone's help with this. Here is my .htaccess configuration just in case and I am using wordpress 3.5.1

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
 RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) public/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ public/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
 # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration file ,i hope that you are using the wordpress on sub domains.
So check the following

Wild card sub domains- Check you have activated the wild card sub domains with your site
Created the directory named "blogs.dir" in the "wp-contents" directory with the permission of "755"
After confirming this try again.

Answer (score -1):

This error is related to `.htaccess`, when it happened to me I had it in the wrong place. Your `.htaccess` needs to be in the **root** of your Wordpress dir. where your `wp-config.php`file is.